# socketio:- event.on in multiple windows

Tags: node.js, events, socket.io

server:-

```
socket.emit('message', 'notification');
```

client:-

```
 socket.on('message', function(data){
        alert(data);
      });
```

The above code triggers `alert` only in last window opened. I want the event to trigger in all client windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding `broadcast` at server does it.

server:-

```
socket.broadcast.emit('message', 'notification');
```

Since `.broadcast` does not relay event to triggering window I suggest using `.emit` as well:-
server:-

```
socket.broadcast.emit('message', 'notification');
socket.emit('message', 'notification');
```